# symfony2 form validation radio buttons

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, radio-button, formbuilder

I am using this code to create symfony2 form:

```
$builder
        ->add('layout_type', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => array(0 => 'Small layout', 1 => 'Big layout'),
                'expanded' => true,
                'disabled' => $disabled
            ))
```

....
           ))

The problem I have is with radio buttons validation (layout_type, choice).

When I don't select any of radio buttons and submit form, data are not inserted in database.
It is correct because radio buttons are obligatory field, but when form is reloaded I don't have message about error for radio buttons. I am getting errors for all other fields correctly.

Twig I am using:

```
<table width="1000">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">{{ form_label(form.layout_type, 'LAYOUT_TYPE') }}</td>
            <td class="widget">{{ form_widget(form.layout_type) }} {{ form_errors(form.layout_type) }}</td>
        </tr>
        ...
```

And for validation I am using annotation:

```
 /**
 * @var Integer
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="NOT_EMPTY")
 */
protected $layoutType;
```

I have problem only with error message for $layoutType radio buttons
Does someone know what can be a problem.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:

'choices'   => array(0 => 'Small layout', 1 => 'Big layout'),
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'disabled' => $disabled,
                    'constraints' => new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'YOUR_MESSAGE'))
```

Comment: Yes it is working. Thanks. But I still cannot understand why annotation doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

before your actual entity

```
class entity {

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $layoutType;
     ........
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. For other fields error messages are working correctly.

Comment: After adding the assert constraint, did you re-generated entities ?